# ios push notification stop working in quick blox

Tags: ios, quickblox

```
-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type {  

    NSString *dt = [[credentials.token description]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    dt = [dt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", dt);

    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");

        NSString *dt =@"123456";
        NSLog(@"Error token is: %@", dt);
        [UserDefaults setObject:dt forKey:NS_device_id];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"PushCredentials: %@", credentials.token);

    [UserDefaults setObject:dt forKey:NS_device_id];

    NSString *deviceIdentifier = [[[UIDevicecurrentDevice]identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    QBMSubscription *subscription = [QBMSubscription subscription];
    subscription.notificationChannel = QBMNotificationChannelAPNSVOIP;
    subscription.deviceUDID = deviceIdentifier;
    subscription.deviceToken = [self.voipRegistry pushTokenForType:PKPushTypeVoIP];

    [QBRequest createSubscription:subscription successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *objects) {
        NSLog(@"Create Subscription request - Success");
    } 
    errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"Create Subscription request - Error");
    }];
}

-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload");
}

-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didInvalidatePushTokenForType:(PKPushType)type {
    NSString *deviceIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    [QBRequest unregisterSubscriptionForUniqueDeviceIdentifier:deviceIdentifier successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
        NSLog(@"Unregister Subscription request - Success");
    } 
    errorBlock:^(QBError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Unregister Subscription request - Error");
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is just a block of code. What is your question? What is your  issue? What have you done to resolve it?

Comment: i am sending notification from quickblox it work till now but suddenly it stop working....i double check my certificate its working but notification not recevied from quickblox can you please help me out thank you

Answer (score 1):

push notifications do not work at all even if send from quickblox admin panel.
Cannot even submit a ticket into quickblox service.

Comment: but it work properly before 3 to 4 days why it is not working now

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they haven't made changes on server in appliance with recent changes in APNS, it is not client-side code. Their support does not answer, strange things are going on.

Answer (score 0):

Their admin server https://admin.quickblox.com/ has a 'Server is on maintenance
Sorry for the inconvenience' message referring users to a blog where the last post was two days ago. My ios app is giving exceptions generated in their api when a new user attempts to log on.
No answer on their phone line either.
Doesnt look good...

Comment: quickblox is up and running again now